# Arranging the alphabet such that every vowel is followed by at least two consonants

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways are there to order the $26$ letters of the English alphabet so that there are at least two consonants immediately following each vowel?

I think $$\frac{(16!\times21)!}{5!\times11!}$$ since there are ${16\choose5}$ ways to place vowels between consonants and there are $21!$ ways to place consonants.

Is this correct?

Comment: How many do you think?

Comment: It is preferred that you show your own efforts at solving the problem so that people may better gauge your level of understanding and what is causing your difficulty.  You'll get more help that way.

Comment: i think (16!*21)!/(5!*11!) scince there are 16C5 ways to place vowels between consonants and there are 21! ways to place consonants.

Comment: No, these are different problems.

Comment: @robertkovacs these are not the same problems.

Comment: While I suppose you meant to write $\frac{16!21!}{5!11!}$, you have not dealt with the condition that there are at least *two* consonants following each vowel.  Also, your attempt should be included in the question itself, rather than the comments, where it might be missed.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough experience with this site. I think I have, because I have supposed that when you pick gap between consonants(or first "gap") next gap is blocked. So, there are 16 valid places to place vowel out of 21. If i am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is essentially finding the number of ways to arrange $21$ C's and $5$ V's in a line such that every V is followed by at least two C's.  This is equivalent to the number of ways to arrange $5$ VCC's and $11$ C's, which is $\binom{16}5$.

Having done that, the only remaining problem is replacing the C's and V's with different permutations of the actual consonants and vowels.  Therefore, the total number of arrangements is $$\binom{16}5\;21!\cdot5!$$